# How to detect out going calls in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

I want to detect outgoing call in android application. I have used TelephonyManager, but it detecting only incoming calls

Answer (score 1):

Use `PhoneStateListener`

```
 private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    number = incomingNumber;
                    Thread_calls.run();
                    //Toast.makeText(ctx, "Incoming: " + incomingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public class OutgoingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
            public OutgoingReceiver() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                Thread_calls.run();
                //Toast.makeText(ctx, "Outgoing: " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
```